# pass by reference and splicing

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to better understand how pass by reference works in relation to splice. I want to have a main array of objects and use another array that has references to the main arrays objects. For example:

```
var mainArray = [
    someObject,
    anotherObject
]
var subArray = [];
subArray.push( mainArray[ 0 ] );
```

What I don't understand is what happens if I splice the original value?

```
mainArray.splice( 0, 1 );
```

Does subArray[ 0 ]:

1. also get spliced?
2. the value still exist since there is a pointer to it?
3. get left with an empty value?

Comment: There **is no** pass-by-reference in JavaScript. The term "pass-by-reference" has a specific meaning in programming (it's a "term of art"): Passing a reference *to a variable* into a function. JavaScript doesn't have that.

Comment: What you're doing above is passing an object reference into a function (by value; the value is the object reference).

Comment: No, yes (but as TJ said, the "pointer" is the value), no....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After this code:

```
var mainArray = [
    someObject,
    anotherObject
];
var subArray = [];
subArray.push( mainArray[ 0 ] );
```

...what you have in memory looks a bit like this:

```
                                                   +−−−−−−−−−−+
someObject−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>| (object) |
                           /  /                    +−−−−−−−−−−+
                           |  |    
                           |  |                     +−−−−−−−−−−+
                           |  |  anotherObject−−−+−>| (object) |
                           |  |                 /   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                           |  |                |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  |                |
subArray−−−−>| (array)   | |  |                |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  |                |
             | length: 1 | |  |                |
             | 0:        |−/  |                |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+    |                |
                              |                |
              +−−−−−−−−−−−+   |                |
mainArray−−−−>| (array)   |   |                |
              +−−−−−−−−−−−+   |                |
              | length: 2 |   |                |
              | 0:        |−−/                 |
              | 1:        |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−/
              +−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note that there is no connection between `mainArray` and `subArray` at all. They both just happen to contain the same value (which is also the value in `someObject`, all three places have an object reference for the same object).

Removing that value from `mainArray` has no effect on `subArray` (or on the objects):

```
mainArray.splice(0, 1);
```

```
                                                   +−−−−−−−−−−+
someObject−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>| (object) |
                           /                       +−−−−−−−−−−+
                           |       
                           |                        +−−−−−−−−−−+
                           |     anotherObject−−−+−>| (object) |
                           |                    /   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                           |                   |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                   |
subArray−−−−>|  (array)  | |                   |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                   |
             | length: 1 | |                   |
             | 0:        |−/                   |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |
                                               |
              +−−−−−−−−−−−+                    |
mainArray−−−−>|  (array)  |                    |
              +−−−−−−−−−−−+                    |
              | length: 1 |                    |
              | 0:        |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−/
              +−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

So based on that:

> 1. also get spliced?

No, changing the contents of `mainArary` has no effect on `subArray`.

> 2. the value still exist since there is a pointer to it?

`subArray`'s value for entry `0` is unaffected.

> 3. get left with an empty value?

No, there's no effect on `subArray` at all.

---

> I am trying to better understand how pass by reference works in relation to splice.

You're confusing two different meanings of the word "reference" there (lots of people do).

"Pass-by-reference" is a term of art in programming. That is, it has a specific meaning: Passing a reference to *a variable* into a function so the function can reach out and change the contents of that variable. JavaScript doesn't have pass-by-reference.

What you're dealing with in your question is *object references*, which have nothing to do with pass-by-reference, it's just that both concepts contain the word "reference" (but in relation to completely different things.)

Object references are values. They tell the JavaScript engine where the object is in memory.

Comment: This is exactly the explanation I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Funny this is very similar to another recent question, though not quite a dupe.

Setting up a data structure that attempts to work with such references across discreet components is a dark path. It's interesting if you're just noodling around with some code, but in a deployed app this is trouble.

You are far better off creating a structure where changes to a model are written to that model by the component making the changes, then the model broadcasts a "dirty data" event (or whatever you want to call it), which contains the new data, that registered listeners (e.g. other components) are listening for. They receive the data payload and use it.

For components that want that data on demand, you inject the service/access the singleton/whatever your framework does, and access it through a getter or some kind of simple factory function.

Mutating objects the way you're doing is increasingly frowned upon. It's better to pass around immutable (or at least copied) versions of the object in question. This way, if that object changes, it's easy to find out where and why. If everything has a reference that actually works (and as you can see above, it often doesn't), a small change to any of them can wreck your morning.

Copying objects, if you're wondering, isn't hard. You can copy an object simply this way (assuming it contains basic objects, primitive types, etc.)

```
let myNewObj = Object.assign ( {}, myOldObj );
let myNewArr = [].concat ( myOldArr );
```

If that object has things like arrays with objects etc. in them, you can deep copy with this old trick:

```
let myFancyObjJSON = JSON.stringify ( myFancyObj )
let copy = JSON.parse ( myFancyObjJSON )
```

Works the vast majority of the time, unless your types are not typical (e.g. Maps with keys that are Symbols have those keys ignored) and some other not-often-encountered day-to-day situations.

Believe me, from experience, rethink your structure (again, unless this is just an experiment).

Answer (score 0):

I've expanded your example a little bit to try to clarify what's going on

```js
var mainArray = [
    {a: 1},
    {b: 2}
]
var subArray = [];
subArray.push( mainArray[ 0 ] );

mainArray.splice( 1, 1 );  // remove b from mainArray

subArray[0].a = 5 // set a in subArray to 5

console.log(mainArray, subArray); // [{a:5}] [{a:5}] a = 5 in both array ( same object )

var third = subArray;

third[0].a = 15;

console.log(mainArray, subArray, third); // [{a:15}] [{a:15}] [{a:15}] 
                                         // the same object a is changed everywhere

third.splice(0, 1);

console.log(mainArray, subArray, third); // [{a:15}] [] []
                                         // mainArray ---> object x ---> x[0] ---> a
                                         // third and subArray ---> object y ---> y[0] ---> a
                                         // there's no link between x and y directly
```